# Routing problems with google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have some problem reaching my 4 Google Compute Engines (gce) located on 2 different accounts, in 2 different zones (europe and us).

The problem is reaching the servers from outside googles network, when i try to connect with telnet most of the connections is just dropped and never reach by the server.

When i do a tcpdump, the packages which is received by the server will be established. However most of the packages does never reach the server, and i dont know where they end up, which is my actually problem..

Between the gce's i have no problem connection to each other, but when i try to connect from both Denmark (2 different ISP's) and Sweden i see the above problems.

Does anyone see something simulair, or might be able to help me out? The problem started 2 hours ago, and i dont know how big the problem is, and i have no personal connections which uses gce as well, so hope someone can give me a hint:

Is it a global problem? Or can you see this as well?

Here is some debug:

```
;( mh@dev:~$ telnet snorestopper.eu 25
Trying 192.158.30.168...
^C
;( mh@dev:~$ telnet snorestopper.eu 25
Trying 192.158.30.168...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
;( mh@dev:~$ ^C
;( mh@dev:~$ telnet snorestopper.eu 80
Trying 192.158.30.168...
^C
;( mh@dev:~$ telnet snorestopper.eu 80
Trying 192.158.30.168...
Connected to snorestopper.eu.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
;) mh@dev:~$ telnet snorestopper.eu 80
Trying 192.158.30.168...
^C
;( mh@dev:~$ telnet snorestopper.eu 80
Trying 192.158.30.168...
Connected to snorestopper.eu.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
```

---

Update, just a little followup to the problem, i have tried to install a new gce, and i saw exactly the same:

```
mh@wupti:~$ telnet 107.178.222.21 80
Trying 107.178.222.21...
Connected to 107.178.222.21.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
mh@wupti:~$ telnet 107.178.222.21 80
Trying 107.178.222.21...
^C
mh@wupti:~$
```

Well.. if anyone have any experiences that would be great to know, otherwise i hope the problem will solve itself within a few minutes/hours..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with GCE, posted on the gce-operations list here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-operations/FuBZbPxIBzg

The initial issue description:

> We're currently investigating inbound connectivity issue with Compute Engine towards zones “europe-west1-a” and “europe-west1-b”, which started around 03:15 US/Pacific.
>   The problem seems localized in Finland, Sweden, and Russia. We will provide more information shortly.

It should be resolved now.